# Getting Javascript to work with a HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on my first Javascript document and I'm not sure what's wrong with this code. I've had my more experienced friend look at it and he can't find anything wrong either. The validators do not output a warning message when I enter something into the fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
     <title>Payment Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="paymentform.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

function validateCard() {
    var x = document.getElementById("1").value;
    if (x.length < 16) {
        alert("Card Number must be 16 numbers long");
        return false;
    }
}

    function validateCVC() {
    var x = document.getElementById("2").value;
    if (x.length != 3) {
        alert("CVC must be 3 digits long");
        return false;
    }
}


function validateName() {
    var x = document.getElementById("3").value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Please enter a name");
        return false;
    }
}

function validateMonth() {
    var x = document.getElementById("4").value;
    if (x < 1 || > 12 || x == "") {
        alert("Must be a number between 1 and 12");
        return false;
    }
 }

function validateYear() {
    var x = document.getElementById("5").value;
    if (x < "2016" || x  == null){
        alert("Must be the year 2016 or higher");
        return false;
    }
}

function allfuncs() {
      validateCard();
      validateCVC();
      validateName();
      validateMonth();
      validateYear();
}
</script>

</head>

<img src="BlackBot logo.png" alt="Black Bot Computers" width="200px" height="100px">
</h1>
<h1 align="center">Payment Form</h1>
<HR COLOR="green" WIDTH="60%">

<body>
<br>
<center><form onSubmit="allfuncs()">

<br>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label>Card number</label>
    <input id="1" class="card-number" type="text" size="20" />
  </div>
<br>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label>CVC</label>
    <input id="2" class="card-cvc" type="text" size="4" />
  </div>
<br>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input id="3" class="card-holdername" type="text" size="20" />
  </div>
<br>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label>Expiry date (MM/YYYY)</label>
    <input id="4" class="card-expiry-month" type="text" size="2" />
    <span></span>
    <input id="5" class="card-expiry-year" type="text" size="4" />
  </div>
<br>
<br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
<br>
<br>

</form></center>
</body>

</html>
```

If anyone can help find a problem it would be a big help!

Comment: You could start by opening the browser console (F12), and note the syntax errors you have, and then just fix those yourself ?

Comment: I'll get you started -> `(x < 1 || > 12 || x == "")`, note how you have `|| > 12`, what should `12` be larger than?

Comment: Sincerely apologise, that was the only error in the document, I just didn't see it

Comment: @Dafzr308 And try to use validation javascript it will more easy to deal with various validation

Answer (score 0):

My console is showing an error in your validateMonth() function . Specifically @  `if (x < 1 || > 12 || x == "").`Just modify your if statement to the following:

function validateMonth() {
    var x = document.getElementById("4").value;

```
 if (x < 1 ||  x > 12 || x == "") {
        alert("Must be a number between 1 and 12");
        return false;
    }
```

}

This should fix your error .

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the form not to continue if validation fails. This is done by returning `false` to the `onSubmit` call in your example. Here's what you need to change in the js.

```
function allfuncs() {
    if(!validateCard()){return false;}
    if(!validateCVC()){return false;}
    if(!validateName()){return false;}
    if(!validateMonth()){return false;}
    if(!validateYear()){return false;}
    return true;
}
```

Then change your `form` call to this.

```
<form onSubmit="return allfuncs();">
```

As pointed out in other comments and answers, you also have a syntax error that is fixed by this.

```
if (x < 1 || x > 12 || x == "") {
```